# How can I update a field with python requests via Prestashop API? In Prestashop 1.7

Tags: python, python-requests, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

If I want to get a specific **Order**, I do this:

```py
import requests, json
r = requests.get('https://mycompany.com/api/orders/4&ws_key=XXX&output_format=JSON')
print r
```

And it works fine. It gives me all the information about the order number 4.

The problem is when I want to update a specific field, for example the **reference** field. If I do this:

```py
data={'ws_key':'XXX',
      'output_format':'JSON',
      'reference': 'TEST'}
r = requests.post('https://mycompany.com/api/orders/4', data=data)
print r
```

I get this output:

```py
[401] Unauthorized
```

I have tried this other option:

```py
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Basic XXX'}
data={'output_format':'JSON',
      'reference': 'TEST'}
r = requests.post('https://mycompany.com/api/orders/4', data=data, headers=headers)
print r
```

But the same result:

```py
[401] Unauthorized
```

How can I modify the field?

Answer (score 0):

As you first example show, you parameters should be inside url instead of data. So you code will be

```
import requests
try:
    from urllib import parse
except Exception as e:
    import urllib as parse

payload = {'ws_key':'XXX',
      'output_format':'JSON'}
data = {'reference': 'TEST'}
url = 'https://mycompany.com/api/orders/4&{}'.format(parse.urlencode(payload))

r = requests.put(url,data=data)
print(r.url)
```

Or

```
payload = {'ws_key':'XXX',
      'output_format':'JSON',
      'reference': 'TEST'}
url = 'https://mycompany.com/api/orders/4&{}'.format(parse.urlencode(payload))
```

But as document described you should put XML file instead of data or json.

> Prestashop Python API: https://github.com/prestapyt/prestapyt

Comment: I don't know where do you put the ws_key in your example.
You create a payload variable that you don't use. 
Moreover, I use python2 and that urllib.parse is for python3

Comment: sry, when i copy my code to here i changed something. And i forgot to check it again

Comment: It gives me this error: XML error : String could not be parsed as XML.
it appears that only accepts XML as input. That is correct?

Comment: This error came from website's response? I ever tried to use `Prestashop Python API` to post data. When i watched my request i found library transform data into XML.

Comment: Yes, the field can be modified with prestapyt, but my purpose is to modify it via requests library.

Comment: It probably need you get you whole XML and modify it, then post/put it again. http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Chapter+5+-+Modification+-+Update+client